# How can I add an EM tag to link_to?

Tags: ruby, tags, eventmachine

I need this output:

```
<li><a href="#"><em>Name</em><img src="images/9.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
```

and I dont know how to add **EM tag** to **link_to**.
my code is:

```
<li><%= link_to image_tag(pic.picture.url(:thumb)), pic, :title => pic.name %></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by @mbratch is definitely the cleaner way to go, however to answer your specific question you do it like this using the block form of `link_to`:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to pic, title: pic.name do %>
    <em><%= pic.name %></em><%= image_tag(pic.picture.url(:thumb)) %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: While this answers the question at hand, I would like to point out that using <em> tags is usually less preferable to using css classes.  I would prefer:  `<%= link_to image_tag(pic.picture.url(:thumb)), pic, :title => pic.name, :class => 'highlight' %>`  and then style `a.highlight` as desired.

Comment: I agree, and that's why I started my answer by saying I liked the answer by @mbratch better for this very reason. But, I was answering his specific question. For all we know there is some reason it needs to be an em tag and not just a style on the link.

Comment: I commented after scanning the code - habit of a coder, just read the code, not the comments :D still, I thought it would be good to have the complete function listed.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to the `link_to`, using `:class => 'bold_link'` for example, and then in CSS define `a.bold_link` to have `font-weight: bold`.